# How would I make sure that all available games are added into the database within a given week?

Tags: java, mysql

The code that I am writing is supposed to add all available games into the database within a given week set by the handler weekNumber.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nflpickem",
                    "root", "root");

            System.out.println("Create USER/GAME (bases)");

            String[] users = {"red", "blue"};
            String[] grps = {"bronze", "gold", "silver"};

            int gameID = 10000;
            int pid = 10000;
            int weekNumber = 1;

             for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < grps.length; y++) { //modified the loop condition for 'grps' to avoid index out of bounds
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO PICKS VALUES (";
                    sql = sql + ++pid + ",";
                    sql = sql + "'" + users[i] + "',";
                    sql = sql + "'" + grps[y] + "',";
                    sql = sql + "" + ++gameID + ",";
                    sql = sql + "" + weekNumber + ",";
                    if (i < users.length/2) { // add all picks for half of the users
                        sql = sql + "'ATL')";
                    } else if (i == 1 && y == 1) { // add some picks for specific user
                        sql = sql + "'BUF')";
                    } else { // add no picks for users
                        sql = sql + "'NO')";
                    }

                    System.out.println(sql);

                    try {
                        conn.createStatement().execute(sql);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    
                }

            }
             
            System.out.println("Table USER created!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("oops:" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the code to populate the table it only shows me 6 out of all available games within a week. The number of games isn't set and is supposed to be open, but no matter how many games I add within the table it always stops at 6 populated games.[The result after running the code in MySQL database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRslV.png) I know I'm missing something very simple but it is slipping my mind as to what it could be.

I have tried to make the week and the game ID number of the groups match, but all of the game ID's start the same no matter the week. I have tried to separate the query into 3 bigger parts but that game me the same result of only showing 3 games. I tried to use a HashSet to use a separate game ID storage system to help populate the table, but it only got through 3 and no more. I tried to force the games into showing me the ones that are directly connected with week 1, however that didn't populate the table either.

Comment: have you debugged your code? Have you checked that it actually reads all the games? have you got any error messages?

Comment: Your code does 6 inserts (2 nested loops over 2 users and 3 groups so 2*3 = 6). Since on each run the values are the same how do you expect there to be more than 6 distinct rows in the table?

Comment: Btw, once you're writing code that is meant to be production ready you need to ditch appending the values directly into the statement as this is a severe security vulnerability. Learn to use `PreparedStatement` instead.

Comment: no error messages displayed in debug mode when I ran it through, and how would I go about fixing the 2 nested loops issue?

Comment: @Bananazoid that isn't an issue. you are actually treating all the information you provide.

Comment: weekNumber  value is always 1. If you want to have more weeks you need to iterate over this value or run your program with weekNumber of different values (it can be an input parameter).

Comment: @Bananazoid, maybe add the third for loop , ` for (int z = 1; z <= weekNumber.length; z++) { 
    ...
    sql = sql + "" + z + ","; // z is replace weekNumner
    ...
 }`